# JPS Miqraot Gedolot

Tags: product-recommendation, translation

There is 5 volume JPS Miqra'ot Gedolot edition. It has Hebrew and English.
I wonder what is the consensus on it?
Are there better options on Chumash Miqra'ot Gedolot in Hebrew and English?